# Should I be wary of receiving phone interviews from out-of state recruiters?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, work-experience

I've been interviewing for a position for last couple of weeks and had a chance to speak with a hiring manager, and two current employees in my position and they all work in different states. I'm starting to get a little uneasy about it. The position is in a city in TX yet I have not spoken with anyone in their office branch in TX.

All the interviewers I spoke with were in three different states. The company is fairly large company and has four child companies. The company I applied for (child company) doesn't have an office in TX. I started digging around and found that it was another company (not the one in the job description) that had an office in TX. It looks like they are wanting to make an offer but I have YET to speak with anyone in TX office.

Should this raise alarms and red flags? Not sure if this is normal practice.

Comment: Have you enquired about that branch, whether you'd speak to someone from that branch at some point (in case you have branch-specific questions), whether they're even hiring for that branch, etc? What responses did you receive to those questions? Have you enquired about the interview process as a whole? There might be an on-site interview at that branch, or you might speak to someone from there later. It's fine to ask such things during interviews.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you worried about? Them trying to trick you into working at a different office? The whole thing being a scam? Pitching up on the first day and no-one even knowing you're supposed to be there? Something else?

Comment: Well, I assumed that the company I applied for was the company that I would be working for. This question never arose. I can't find any information on the company that's in my area. I will probably decline the offer as there's just so many red flags. I usually like to have an in-person interview with the manager, co-workers, tour the office, company culture, etc..I'm assuming you've accepted offers without in-person interviews based on your comments?

Comment: When they ask "do you have any questions", that's your cue for clarifying this. It's highly unlikely that they'd be intentionally lying to you about in which office you'd be working - that just doesn't make sense, but there might be a miscommunication about that (all the more reason to clarify). I wouldn't consider this a red flag with only the details given. No, I haven't accepted a role without an on-site interview, but some companies do that.

Comment: Might they be trying to hire to actually build an office in TX which is not yet there, but all of those people will be moving to?

Comment: @skymingen, they have an office in TX, but it's a different company than the one I applied for. I'm just surprised they didn't tell me this up-front.

Comment: @noah: I'm unclear as to how any of that matters.

Answer (score 2):

No I don't see why you would be weary of receiving phone interviews from out-of state recruiters.

This is just a way to simplify the logistics of the interview, it is relatively common practice (I got hired into my current job through a skype interview and some phone calls).

If you have any concerns about the actual company or anything else, ask them on the phone interview. It is perfectly acceptable to ask to meet them before signing a work contract.